# In how many ways can the votes of n voters be split among k candidates?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are `n` voters and `k` candidates. In how many different ways can the vote be split among the candidates?

To be clear, I am only concerned with the number of votes that each candidate gets, not with how individual voters vote.

Each voter can and must vote for only one candidate.

Comment: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) works well here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ votes for $k$ candidates.

If you line up the votes by candidate, you'll have groups of votes for each one. (Unpopular candidates may not have any votes.)

We can insert $k-1$ dividers in the line of votes to cordon them off by candidate. So if we have $n+k-1$ spaces, we'll have room for all of the votes and the dividers.

Now the problem gets down to how many ways you can choose the spaces for the $k-1$ dividers in the line of $n+k-1$ spaces.

This is the essence of [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars). Can you take it from here?

Comment: Your answer explained the solution very well. Thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

We seek to find the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k =n$ in nonnegative integers. Consider $n$ dots and $k-1$ dividers arranged in a row. The dividers divide the row into $k$ sections, and the number of dots in each gives the $x_i$. There are $n+k-1 \choose k-1$ ways to arrange these, and so this is the number of ways votes can be cast.